# QT Connection Error [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''.QODBC3: Unable to connect

Tags: sql-server, qt, odbc

I am trying to connect my qt application to ms sql database. I dont know server machine's IP addres and PORT number. I allready have Data Source Name in System DSN. Here is the sample of my code :

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER={serverName};DATABASE=dbname;UID=username;PWD=password;WSID=.;Trusted_connection=yes");
bool ok = db.open();

    if(ok == true){
        qDebug()<<"connected";
    }
    else{
        qDebug()<<"not connected";
        qDebug()<<db.lastError().text();
    }
```

And i get this error :

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user
> 'xxx'. QODBC3: Unable to connect.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things here.

First, you *either* use windows authentication, *or* you use SQL authentication. Not both.

If your connection string specifies `Trusted_connection=yes`, or `integrated security=SSPI`, then you're using windows authentication.

If your connection string specifies `uid=someuser; pwd=somepassword` then you're using SQL auth.

Pick one.

Now, if you're using an ODBC DSN, then the DSN already specifies the driver and server, so you don't need that in your application connection string. Instead, you just tell the application which DSN to use.

Let's say you created your DSN and called it "MySqlServer". Then your code will look like this:

```
db.setDatabaseName("MySqlServer");
```

Now, if the DSN is set up to use windows authentication, that's all you need to do. On the other hand, if it's set up to use SQL authentication, then you can take the credentials already specified in the DSN, or set a username and password in your code:

```
db.setUserName("myUserName");
db.setPassword("myPassword");
```

Comment: If I use this app on multiple computers do I need to change system DSN on all computers?

Comment: An ODBC dsn is stored locally on a computer. If you want to use the DSN based connection on multiple computers, then yeah, you will need to create the DSN on each computer. The other option would be to not use a DSN at all, and instead specify a full connection string, with the driver, server, etc. Much like you have in your question, but one which is properly constructed. Check out https://www.connectionstrings.com/ for assistance with that.

Comment: But i don't have server machines IP address and PORT number just have servername db name username and password enough? and in this case do i need to use QMYSQL instead of QODBC? By the way thanks for your answer.

Comment: @trytobedeveloper If you are building the connection string fully in code (rather than using a DSN), you will need driver, servername, database name, and then either a user name and password, or tell it to use integrated security. From what I can tell you can definitely still use QODBC, but I am not an expert on QT, so you might want to read up on some other threads on this site to get more info.